# asp.net mvc 3 SelectList with a decimal type

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a decimal value that I was trying to include in a drop down and the selected value was not working.  I messed around with the code for a while with no luck.  Eventually I used the exact same code but changed everything from decimal to int and it works.

Before (InitialRewardPercent is a decimal):

> @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.InitialRewardPercent,
>   CommonServices.GetRewardTermInitialPercents(Model.InitialRewardPercent))

CommonServices.GetRewardTermInitialPercents returns a select list and selects the value I pass in:

> return new SelectList(rewardTermInitialPercents, "Percent",
>   "PercentDisplay", selectedPercent);

After (InitialRewardPercent is an int):

> @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.InitialRewardPercent,
>   CommonServices.GetRewardTermInitialPercents(Model.InitialRewardPercent
>   * 100))

I did * 100 because I wanted to go from 0.25 to 25.  Basically all I did was switch the variable type from decimal to int and the SelectList is now properly marking the correct row as selected.

Can anyone else get the SelectList to work with a decimal value or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public decimal InitialRewardPercent { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Percents { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        InitialRewardPercent = 0.25m,
        Percents = new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "0.15", Text = "15%" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "0.25", Text = "25%" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "0.35", Text = "35%" },
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.InitialRewardPercent, Model.Percents)
```

As expected, the second item is preselected in the dropdown when the view is shown. So I guess somehow in your example there is no value in the list that matches the value of `InitialRewardPercent` so the first is always preselected.

Comment: Thanks for the setup. When I did it my values in the select list were also decimals, I see yours are string.  That must have been what I was doing wrong.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue.

i was using `decimal.ToString()` to set the `SelectListItem.Value` so `(4.5m).ToString() == "4.5"`

however the model property would add an extra Zero because it was stored as 4.50m in the database so `(4.50m).ToString() == "4.50"`

The fix in my situation was to use a formatted string - `decimal.ToString("0.00")` so it would be the same as the model property.

```
public static IList<SelectListItem> ToSelectList(this IEnumerable<decimal> values, string format = "0.00")
{
            return values
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.ToString(), Value = x.ToString(format) })
                .ToList();
}
```